# VPA program for compare values in array and give a result (MS Excel)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, compare

I have some variables in an array. Those may be "Yes", "No", "NA" or "-".
For example i have an array arr(1 t0 5) . The values would be 'Yes, Yes, No, No & Yes'. The length of array may vary. Like these the combination may vary given that above four values ("Yes", "No", "NA" or "-") 
My requirement is that i want to compare the values in array and give a result in a cell of excel work sheet. For example, if all values in array are either 'Yes' or 'NA' then result should be "Yes". If any one value is 'No' or '-' then result should be "No".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Application.Match` to find if you have at least 1 "No" in your `arr` array.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckArray()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim Res As Variant, r As Variant
Dim Result As String   

' test #1: at least 1 "No" or "-"  in array
arr = Array("Yes", "-", "Yes", "NA", "Yes")

Res = Application.Match(Array("No", "-"), arr, 0)
For Each r In Res
    Result = "Yes" ' init value
    If Not IsError(r) Then ' <-- at least 1 result of "-" or "No" found
        Result = "No"
        Exit For
    End If
Next r    
' === The result is "No" ===


' test #2: there are no "No" or "-" in the array
arr = Array("Yes", "NA", "Yes", "NA", "Yes")

Res = Application.Match(Array("No", "-"), arr, 0)
For Each r In Res
    Result = "Yes" ' init value
    If Not IsError(r) Then ' <-- at least 1 result of "-" or "No" found
        Result = "No"
        Exit For
    End If
Next r

' === The result is "Yes" ===

End Sub
```

Comment: I like especially the fact that the answer is self-contained including a test case without any prerequisites. Awesome!

Comment: This is slow as hell! Avoid using cell functions like `Application.Match` a loop through a bunch of cells is much faster. I just run a test with your function and 30000 `yes` and one `no` at 30001. average 7-8 seconds. And same with a loop like in my answer 0,4 seconds!

Comment: My bad :( you are right. Forget what I said. I was completely wrong. You got my vote.

Comment: Oh but this was just really dump from me, because I missed the `E-05` in the end of `8.63164493441582E-05` and this shouldn't happen to me.

Comment: @Peh you can read here : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28389407/Match-vs-Loop.html

Comment: Yes of course my brain was still narcotized from lunch, nevermind

Comment: Hello Mr. Shai Rado, thank you for your very fast response. I hope this code may very useful for me. Actually my array length may be vary as i mentioned in my question. arr(1 to n) where, n is count of rows based on my some other conditions. I use 'ReDim' to define array length inside a 'for' loop. Now how i could rewrite your code? kindly help me.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSubbiyan it doesn't matter how large your `arr`might be , once you populated your `arr` , use the rest of the code below. You do know hot to populate your `arr` array dynamicaly, based on it's size ?

Comment: @ShaiRado
I am sorry i am totally new to VBA. 
Sorry i couldn't copy here my entire code. Please help me how to populate array. I use DIM arr() as Variant; inside my For loop i use ReDIm arr(0 to m). then i assign values to array from other cells when my If-then condition are true, arr(y) = Cells(j, 27). Where y starts from 0. I need further help from you. Please do the needful.

Comment: @ShaiRado Your code is working. Thank you very much.